# How to connect Node JS API using the IIS service account?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, windows, iis, production-environment

I've recently deployed Node JS API using the production account and it's communicating with DB using the DB credentials.

Unfortunately, we've recently encountered an issue with the DB account and we're being advised to use service account instead of production one.

Our .Net we APIs are working fie because we've options to add service account in our IIS pool but I don't know how to do this for Node APIs.

We're unable to communicate with SQL server account.

Is there any way by which we can host Node JS APIs using the IIS server by configuring the IIS Server pool.

Just so you know our database is configured using the windows authentications instead of SQL server authentication.

Pls help me get this issue resolved. It's fist time I'm stuck with this kind of issues don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the IIS Application Pool Identity? This will enable the application to connect another service with a custom/windows identity.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities
Worker processes in IIS 7 run as Network service by default. Network Service is a built-in windows identity. It is relatively low-privileged. If we wish to configure a custom account for our Application Pool identity in IIS, we could select the App Pool of your website, right-click for Advanced Settings, then select the ellipsis button in the identity section of the settings.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Hi Abraham, thanks for your quick response. This is how I've hosted my application by using the custom/windows identity. Unfortunately, I need help with hosting the Node JS APIs. Can it be hosted using the IIS by selecting the custom pool Identity (Service account).

Comment: I didn’t experience that host NodeJS API in IIS, not to mention that whether custom pool identity works. Refer to the below links about hosting the NodeJS application in IIS.
https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx